# Replace JSON fields

Tags: php, json

I created this php script so I can get data from a MySQL database as JSON, much like a baby web service. What I created can be seen bellow.

```
$category_id = $_GET["CategoryID"];
$sub_id = $_GET["RootID"];

// Connect to our db (MySQL)
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','xxxxxxxx','xxxxx') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_select_db('bridgeapp',$link) or die('Cannot select the DB');  

// Default charset
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $link);

// Show all subcategories based on $category_id value
if (isset($category_id)) {
    $query = "SELECT id, name FROM vrfmp_jbusinessdirectory_categories WHERE parent_id = '".$category_id. "'";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

}

// What happens if CategoryID is empty ? (Show Parental Categories)
if (empty($category_id)) {
    $query = "SELECT id, name FROM vrfmp_jbusinessdirectory_categories WHERE level = 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

}


// Fetch data from the db
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
//    $rows = str_replace("name", "title", "$rows");
}

// Echo $rows in JSON format
echo json_encode($rows);

//Disconnect from our db
@mysql_close($link);
```

Running this returns what I wanted it to.

[When Category ID is empty](http://api.offercat.com/v1/getCategories.php)

[When Category ID has a value](http://api.offercat.com/v1/getCategories.php?CategoryID=82)

What I would like to do is to replace the "name" field with "title" in the JSON object. Any help on how I could do that with PHP ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$rows['title'] = $rows['name']; unset($rows['name']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alias for column

```
SELECT id, name AS `title` FROM ...
```

or

```
$rows[] = [
    'id' => $r['id'],
    'title' => $r['name']
];
```

Comment: Both great and simple solutions. Thank you very much.